# Equally spaced out circles with lines between the text, and centered text below the circles

Tags: html, css

Here's almost what I'm trying to do:

[image: screenshot of rendered current code]

The problem with this is I want the text to be centered underneath the yellow, but if I do that, I don't know how to keep the lines between the yellow dots connected to each other.  Here's a Codepen link to all the code and CSS to generate what I have above: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GdwyyK

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="status-bar">
    <li>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>bar</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>baz</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>qux</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>blahblahblah</div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.container {
  max-width: 100vw;
  width: 950px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 800px;
}

ul.status-bar {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 15px;

  li {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;

    &:not(:last-child) {
      flex: auto;
      // background-color: purple;
    }

    &:not(:last-child):after {
      content: "";
      border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
      flex: 1;
    }
  }

  li div {
    &:not(:last-child) {
      padding: 5px;
      height: 25px;
      width: 25px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 25px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 1px solid black;
      background-color: yellow;
      position: relative;
    }

    &:last-child {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -20px;

      text-align: center;
    }
  }
}
```

How do I center the "foo", "bar", etc. relative to the dots they're below and still have the lines between the dots connected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it differently like this will less of code.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  max-width: 100vw;
  width: 950px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  padding:5px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

ul.status-bar {
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /*I used gradient for the line*/
  background: linear-gradient(blue, blue)50% 20px/100% 2px no-repeat;
}

ul.status-bar li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

ul.status-bar li div:not(:last-child) {
  padding: 5px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
}


/*Hide the overflow of the gradient*/

ul.status-bar li:first-child {
  background: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 50%, lightgrey 0);
}

ul.status-bar li:last-child {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, lightgrey 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="status-bar">
    <li>
      <div>1</div>
      <div>foo</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>2</div>
      <div>b</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>3</div>
      <div>bazjkhj j</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>4</div>
      <div>qx</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>5</div>
      <div>blahblahblah</div>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: I see that this works, but I don't understand how.  Can you explain it a bit?  What is centering the bottom text?

Comment: @DanielKaplan yes sure. The idea is simple : we have the main container (the ul) as a flex one with a space-bewteen centreing the li, then each li is also a flex container with a column direction to have the text bottom the numbe and to easily center also